# Broken category pagination

Tags: categories, pagination

For some reason the below code works until I hit the third page and gives 404. Is it possible to fix it without using any plugins?

```
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query('cat='. $id .'&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

<?php get_the_content() ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Previous', 'themename' ) ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next', 'themename' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
```

Comment: why not create a new instance of $posts array? like $new_query = new WP_Query(' ... and i think you need to use wp_reset_query(); after the custom WP_Query.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new instance of WP_Query and at the end use wp_reset_query(); like this:

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $my_query->query('cat='. $id .'&posts_per_page=4&paged='.$paged);
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>

<?php get_the_content() ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php if (  $my_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Previous', 'themename' ) ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( __( 'Next', 'themename' ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, do not use `$wp_query = null`, use `wp_reset_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code i use:

```
    <?php $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts("category_name=".$cat."&showposts=20&paged=".$paged."");

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        the_content();

    endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation2">
        <div class="navleft"><?php next_posts_link('Older Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="navright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries') ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php $wp_query = $temp_query; ?>
```